# Getting list of tokens in Urbancode

Tags: security, token, ucd

I'm implementing a workflow including many steps. A final one is a component deployment in IBM UrbanCode.

I have:

- admin credentials (login, password),
- login of user responsible for deployment (token in UCD already exists)

Is it possible to fetch a list of declared tokens (as admin) using REST API? All I can see is the method for creating a token.

Regards,
Norbert

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.../security/authtoken/

(Not officially supported)